# How do I handler error for a specific constraint in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In this case I would like to know if there is a possibility to Control foreign's error in the procedure for any of those specific constraint **fkt3_1** and **fkt3_2**.

Try to Handle the errors separately

Tables Example:

```sql
create table t1(
    id int,
    name varchar(20),
    constraint pkt1 primary key(id)
)

create table t2(
    id int,
    name varchar(20),
    constraint pkt2 primary key(id)
)

create table t3(
    id int,
    fromt1 int,
    fromt2 int,
    constraint pkt1 primary key(id),
    constraint fkt3_1 foreign key(fromt1) references t1(id),
    constraint fkt3_2 foreign key(fromt2) references t2(id)
)
```

Procedure:

```sql
delimiter $$
create procedure ins(pid int, toT1 int, toT2 int)
begin
    declare exit handler for 1452 select 'Error Found for fkt3_1 and fkt3_2';
    insert into t3 values(pid,toT1,toT2);
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Are you going to insert / update / delete from other tables in that stored proc, which may violate other fk restrictions?

Comment: This example is just for insert situation

I would like to make something like this:

`declare exit handler for 1452,fkt3_1 select 'Error Found for fkt3_1';`
-- and --
`declare exit handler for 1452,fkt3_2 select 'Error Found for fkt3_2';`

I know that the example that I gave you does not work, but I think it is good example of what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no and yes.

No, you cannot declare handlers that would fire only if a particular foreign key triggers mysql error 1452. You can only define handlers that will trigger if any piece of code results in error 1452. See mysql's documentation on [DECLARE ... HANDLER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-handler.html) syntax.

Having said that, you can declare a variable within the stored procedure and set its value before you make any changes to t3 records to indicate that t3 will be changed. If the subsequent code triggers error handler for 1452 error, then you can check the value of the variable and make a decision in the body of the handler how handle that paricular occurance of error.

Another solution is to place the definition of the error handler in such way, that it only applies that particular piece of code within the stored procedure, which modifies t3 data. Error handler in essence behave like variables, the handler applies to all statements in the block in which it is defined.